# Im' getting an error when deploying an artifact in my repository in a Nexus server:

Tags: jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin, cloudbees

We have migrated cloudbees jenkins jobs to open source jenkins and it's working fine on the cloudbees jenkins with same code but getting below error while testing on the open source jenkins.

Is there any difference and any idea on this?

Prompting two errors on two environments,
when tried with pre-prod getting this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project MassUploadModel: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request. -> [Help 1]

when tried with sys getting this error:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
> [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [ERROR] /jenkins/workspace/jenkins job/MassUploadUI/src/com/directory/massuploadapps/view/backing/com/directory/massupload/ui/pages/ManualMassCreation.java:[1889,48] error: incomparable types: Object and boolean

why it's getting error on opensource jenkins and same code is working fine for cloudbees jenkins?